# React Native developer Menu not loading

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Developer menu in ios simulator will not launch with either `cmd + D` or `cmd + ctrl +  z`

- things i've checked (in no order) :

  - `cmd + r` works properly
  - myApp and myAppTests schemes are set to debug mode
  - **Slow Animations** is off
  - **Hardware > Keyboard > Connect Hardware Keyboard** is on
  - `watchman 4.7.0` is installed with `brew install watchman` (--HEAD needed libtoolize, in which brew changed to glibtoolize, therefore ./autogen couldn't find it )
  - Cleaned out Derived Data folder
  - Created new scheme for target
  - Upgraded XCode to 8.2.1 -> 8.3.1
  - `react-native start --clear-cache` starts successfully, `react-native run-ios` builds successfully
- Other Issues

  - `nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 1262 Connection has no connected handler` run indefinitely
  - `react-native run-ios` outputs

  Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/zelosApp.app/Info.plist
          Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not ExistCommand failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/zelosApp.app/Info.plist
          Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
- Versions

  - react-native = "^0.43.3"
  - watchman = "4.7.0"
  - xcode =  "8.3.1"

Any tips / questions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you might need to upgrade your react-native....Create a fresh project and check if dev menu appears or not on pressing cmd+d. 
 https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12832

Comment: remove watchman completely. Install it manually(dont use brew). This worked for me.

Answer (score 54):

This happens to me too once in a while, and I have not been able to figure out why. However, one workaround is to select Device -> Shake in the simulator menu.

Comment: Ironically, this is the only working solution for me

Comment: Or equivalently, Ctrl+Cmd+Z

Answer (score 2):

Are you using cocoa pods?

I had this issue as well. I believe the issue is from React being included twice. Once from your main project, and once through the Pods workspace.

Try the fix here: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg/issues/621

Namely the post install fix on the Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer_representation|
  installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if target.name == "React"
          target.remove_from_project
      end
  end
```

end

Then, remove any references to the React framework like in linked frameworks in the Xcode project.

I'm able to bring the debug menu back up.

Comment: Perfect! You save my day.

Answer (score 0):

The error was with my importing react in my podfile. React Native .43  found here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10366

Answer (score 0):

Search your `MainApplication.java` for any `import ... BuildConfig`. For example `import androidx.multidex.BuildConfig;` and REMOVE it

Answer (score 0):

For my case in iOS simulator, ctrl+D works but sometimes it doesn't :(
so you can use  Ctrl+Cmd+Z as a backup command :)

Answer (score 0):

Xcode > Scheme > Edit scheme > Build configuration should be debug